# How to cleanly remove a circular dependency cause by a forward ref

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 13 I'm doing some tab mechanism where a parent container keeps a reference of his childs pane, and the pane requires to call one method from the parent.

In *component A* I'm doing :

```
  @ContentChildren(ComponentB) items: QueryList<ComponentB>;
```

In *component B* I have to do:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => ComponentA)) cpa: ComponentA,
  ) {
    this.cpa = cpa;
  }
```

<strike>One fix would be create an interface for `ComponentA` just to avoid the hard reference. But it would mean keep the code and the interface updated.</strike>

Are there some ways to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, maybe you can introduce a kind of `Subject` in some service (probably the "basic one" will be enough in your situation). In your child components (tabs) you should call `.next` on it and you parent would be subscribed to it and "listening" to child components calling `.next()` to the subject.
Inside `.subscribe()` in parent you would call that specific function that needs to be fired upon some child component activity.

That's how we can omit this reference thingy.

Comment: yeah I guess I ll go with something like this, but I also require 2 get property from the parent. so Maybe I have to rethink the architecture a bit if there is no other solution

Comment: Great, look at CD strategies. Maybe `OnPush` will come in handy. Write here if you get stuck